# USB HUB for OTG

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-host, usb-hub, otg

I have designed a custom board with Processor which is having a dedicated USB 2.0 OTG port. I want to convert it to 4 USB OTG ports. so I was thinking to use the USB 2.0 HUB with OTG support for 4 downstream ports.

I checked the portfolio of TI but they do not have Hub supporting OTG. They have TUSB4041IPAPR.
This does not support OTG.

Is it possible to make 4 OTG ports via hub or I'm doing something fundamentally wrong ?

If there is any USB Hub with OTG then please suggest.
Please help me to clear my doubt.
Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Comment: You might want to describe how you think your device with 4 OTG ports should work. When you have one port on a MCU, the MCU is either host or device. When you add a hub, how would you expect your MCU with one OTG port to possibly work with four OTG ports, and how should the hub handle different ports when multiple hosts and devices are connected? It may even be better to start what do you think OTG means, so we have something to build on - you may have misunderstood what it means.

Comment: As Justme said, it's important we understand what you mean by "OTG" here. Note that OTG properly refers to a port that can be either a USB host or a USB device. (The USB bus architecture is not symmetric. A single host can talk to a tree of up to 127 devices.) Sometimes the "OTG" term is incorrectly used for just a USB host port (especially on small gadgets/single board computers).

Comment: So, are you looking for a way to make your device appear as devices for 4 different USB hosts simultaneously (like a KVM switch would), or truly have dual roles for each connector?

Comment: Hi, @Justme Thanks for your comment. I have answered this question as per my understanding. Can you please check if it is right ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, @raek I have gone through the USB architecture after your comment. Can you check if answer is correct ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Brt: That looks right to me! Great explanation! "Consequently, the hub will recognize the upstream as a host, and my custom board will function solely as a host, never as a device." <-- Yep, this is it. It is only the custom board that can switch roles. The ports of the hub have fixed roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After studying USB architecture and specifications, I realized I lacked a solid grasp of the fundamentals. Here's a summary for everyone:

In the USB tree, the Host (e.g., PC) is consistently connected upstream, while the Device (e.g., mouse, pen drive, keyboard) is always connected downstream.

An OTG port implies the ability to function as both host and device. The Micro B cable includes an ID pin, representing the host/device mode. The OTG host controller in the processor reads this ID pin to determine whether to operate as a host or device once the cable is plugged into the receptacle connector.

A hub has dedicated upstream (only 1) and downstream (4) ports. Only a host can connect upstream, and a device can connect downstream. This means the hub facilitates connecting one host (upstream) to multiple devices (downstream), not one device to multiple hosts.

In my scenario, if the custom board processor requires OTG functionality, it should directly connect to the Micro B connector. The processor reads the ID pin status and operates in host/device mode accordingly.

If I opt for a hub in between, I must connect the D+ and D- lines of the processor's OTG pins to the upstream port of the hub. Consequently, the hub will recognize the upstream as a host, and my custom board will function solely as a host, never as a device. Adding a hub in this way restricts the processor from being detected as a device, thereby preventing true OTG functionality.

For those interested, the following document greatly aided my understanding.

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-AN57294_USB_101_An_Introduction_to_Universal_Serial_Bus_2.0-ApplicationNotes-v09_00-EN.pdf%3FfileId%3D8ac78c8c7cdc391c017d072d8e8e5256&ved=2ahUKEwjzlqDW5NiCAxWYzjgGHaMwCWoQFnoECA8QAQ&usg=AOvVaw3hz3VYpgPVyyBWI-VqJG7t

Thanks.